# Spring Jpa Bulk Insert whole data or Update some fields of entity if already available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Problem:
I have a process running which will periodically grab 500 records from outside and insert it to the DB.
How can i check efficiently below case using spring JPA,

1. How to insert data if there is no records (non primary_key column which is unique too)?
2. How to update only some fields if there is a record?

or

How to do saveOrUpdate on bulk records either on all columns or only selected columns using Spring JPA?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the source code of `Spring Data JPA`, you'll find:

```java
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

  if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
    em.persist(entity);
    return entity;
  } else {
    return em.merge(entity);
  }
}
```

the `save` operation is a mix of add and update. So by using the method `save()` or `saveAll()`, you have already achieved the function of `saveOrUpdate`.

To take more control of the above upsert behavior, you can use `@DynamicUpdate` annotation on the entity class, which means the update SQL generated by JPA will only access the changed columns.

The above information is not enough to use JPA correctly in your situation. If you choose JPA, you must do database access in an `object` way. To process the 500 records, the signal of `unique` must be defined by one of the following conditions:

- the primary key
- the unique constraint

I suggest you use the second one since the primary key is used to mark the unique at the database level. And then, with JPA, you should find data in your database that existed in the new 500 records, update their modified columns, use `saveAll()` to update them. And then handle the left part, build entities and use `saveAll()` to insert them.

You may have noticed that the `compare and update then save operation in memory` method I used above is not atomic, and may cause `ConstraintViolationException` when inserting repeat data, there are two ways to handle this:

- If the data is not that serious, you can just do the above operations but remain some space for the exception to happen, you can either log the information for a manual fix or just do nothing. But remember to catch the exception, don't make the update operation rollbacked.
- If you are indeed serious about the data, you can make the whole operation synchronized either by using the `synchronized` keyword or distributed lock.

To be honest, I'm not satisfied with JPA on the batch upsert, it's not atomic, not safe, and not fast. I think it's because there is not a commonly implemented `upsert` pattern in all DBMSs and thus ORM gives up on the function partly. I sincerely recommend you to use `upsert` operation with raw SQL implemented by the database your system chose, like MYSQL [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Sample code below:

```java
  public int upsert(List<Employee> employees) {

      String sqlPattern = "INSERT INTO employee (id, code, name)\n" 
              + "VALUES %s\n"
              + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name      = values(name);";

      List<String> values = employees.stream()
              // build something like (1, '10001', 'Foo Bar')
              .map(employee -> buildRecord(employee))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

      String sql = String.format(sqlPattern, StringUtils.join(values, ", "));

      return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, Map.of());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. So one way i can think of is UPSERT using stored procedure and calling the procedure from Spring. Does this still give best performance do you think? like again giving burden to SP not the application layer. Is any way i can send a list of object like List<Employee> while calling a stored procedure via spring?

Comment: Stored Procedure separates the logic from code, it's efficient but hard to debug, so I recommend you to make up raw SQL(updated in the answer) and execute the raw SQL directly. @Satscreate

Comment: so grab and compare and insert or update using native sql query is the way to go am i right?

Comment: No, compare has been achieved with the SQL and unique constraint on code column. Just grab the data and execute the sql, new data will be inserted, old data will get updated. @Satscreate

Comment: in my case am using Microsoft SQL server as a database, can MERGE be the alternate for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: Yes, that's it, but you must have a source table while using merge, you can use [Bulk Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/bulk-copy-operations-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to create temp table if you are using C# but it seems you are not in this situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227594/discussion-between-lebecca-and-satscreate).